# Recursive CosmosDB stored procedure to return nested data without response.setBody()

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm in the process of building a stored procedure in CosmosDB. The purpose of the stored procedure is to recursively get all child documents which relates to a parent document in my collection.

The steps are as follows:

- Get parent documents
- For each parent documents call `MyRecursiveFunction`
- `MyRecursiveFunction` gets child documents for the parent document
- `MyRecursiveFunction` *should* return child documents to the parent

.

```
function GetGroups(Id) {
    var context = getContext();
    var collection = context.getCollection();
    var response = context.getResponse();

    query = "MY QUERY"

    var accepted = collection.queryDocuments(collection.getSelfLink(), query,
        function (err, documents, responseOptions) {
            if (err) {
                throw new Error("Error" + err.message);
            }
            if (documents.length === 0) {
                throw "Unable to find document"
            }
            for (let i = 0; i < documents.length; i++) {
                MyRecursiveFunction(documents[i]) //<--- Assemble hierarchy
            }
        }
    )
    if (!accepted) {
        throw "Some error happened"
    }

    function MyRecursiveFunction(document) {
        for (let i = 0; i < document.children.length; i++) {

            query = "MY QUERY TO GET DOCUMENT BY ID"

            var accepted = collection.queryDocuments(collection.getSelfLink(), query,
                function (err, child, responseOptions) {
                    if (err) {
                        throw new Error("Error" + err.message);
                    }
                    if (child.length === 0) {
                        throw "Unable to find documents"
                    }
                    return child[0] //<------ How do I return this to parent caller?
                }
            )
            if (!accepted) {
                throw "Some error happened"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem here is, that I'm having a hard time understanding how I can return the data which were fetched inside `MyRecursiveFunction`. The only way in which I seem to be able to do so, is if I do response.setBody(child[0]) - But obviously this sends a response to my API.

Using the returned accept property from `collection.queryDocuments()` only returns `true` or `false`

Therefore, my question boil down to the following:

- How do I return the data from `MyRecursiveFunction` to the calling parent function?
- In case I want to use a continuation token and I achieve to return data to my parent function, will this way of structuring my Stored procedure limit my possibility to use a continuation token, since its basically two individual calls?

Comment: This is not possible in a stored proc. Overall though I would avoid using stored procedures for queries (especially at high volumes) as they only execute on the primary replica and thus only have 1/4 of the provisioned throughput to execute with.

Comment: @MarkBrown Thank you for your reply. But as far as I understand, the only way to do ACID transactions is to execute my queries in a stored procedure. That is, compared to i.e. entity framework, with the use of the CosmosDB SDK I cannot complete my transactions in bulk, in an ALL or NONE fashion ?

Comment: Transactions apply to data being written. There is no such mechanism to do a query in a transaction.